# spring thymeleaf text next line

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I would like to pass on a message from my controller back to my thyme leaf template and set the value on mutiple lines.

in my controller , i set a text like this.

```
String message="item A \n item B \n Item C \n Item D"; //it could be 4 values, could 10 values.

modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", message);
```

In my thymeleaf template, i set it back like this.

```
<p th:utext="${successMessage}"></p>
```

I want it to be displayed like

```
item A
item B
item C
item D
```

in the front end, not all in one line. how do i do it? thanks alot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) My suggestion would be to pass it back as an array.

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("item A", "item B", "Item C", "Item D");
modelAndView.addObject("successMessages", messages);
```

HTML:

```
<p th:each="message: ${messages}" th:text="${message}"></p>
```

2) If you don't want to do that, you can of course use th:utext, but you'd have to use `<br />` instead of `\n`.

3) Another option would be to continue to use `\n` and use `white-space: pre` in your css.

```
<p style="white-space: pre;" th:text="${successMessage}"></p>
```

Comment: #3 is the best answer

Comment: @metroids, #2 th:utext works for me, I've added <br/> from java side and it prints all of them one after other in lines as desired. Thanks!

Comment: @Metroids, #2 suggestion perfectly works. Here is my case: `<td th:utext="${category.nameEn} + (${#strings.isEmpty(category?.descriptionEn)} ? '' : ('<br><br>' + ${category.descriptionEn}))"></td>`

Comment: #3 no good for outlook